# Flow chart document symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, flow-charts

I am doing an old-style flow chart with TiKz, and I am defining my nodes with the `\tikzstyle` command (example `\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]` for the start and stop nodes), but I haven't been able to find or create this figure:[image: The document symbol]

It is used to represent documents in flow charts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The good news is that this shape is already defined in the `shapes.symbols` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[tape,tape bend top=none,draw,font=\sffamily]{I'm a tape.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, `\tikzstyle{io} = [tape, tape bend top = none]` works like a charm!

Comment: @AlejandraRomero You're welcome! Please use `\tikzset{io/.style={tape, tape bend top = none}}` instead, the reason being that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.